# AngularFileSaver saves broken file

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to generate pdfs on server side, and also PHP gd lib to apply text on images. Both of them are sent via REST API to allow user download them (there are different methods for pdf and jpg).

On the client side I'm using AngularFileSaver for webpack, which uses Blob and FileSaver services, but it's not working fine, because saved files are broken (pdf is empty, jpg cannot display image).

I'm pretty sure that it's not a problem with server side sripts, since I used wkhtmltopdf in my other project and it was fine.

Here is my client side code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/cloud/files/pdf',
  headers : {
    'Authorization' : 'some_token',
    'Content-Type'  : 'application/pdf'
  },
  responseType : 'blob'
}).done(function(data) {
  var fileName = "sample.pdf";
  var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
  FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName);
});
```

I tried with different 'type' attribute of Blob, and also ajax's responseType (blob or arrayBuffer) and the result was always the same.

I have no other ideas what may be wrong, after spending hours of reading about this. I'm sure that someone can give me some clues :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's ajax and the responsetype have never worked. Since you are dealing with binary data and jQuery response is always text, that is what might cause the saved file to be broken - I suggest you move away from jQuery and use XHR or fetch

```
fetch(url, {
    headers: {Authorization : 'some_token'}
})
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => saveAs(blob, 'sample.pdf'))
```